# Subscribe to an array with rivets

Tags: events, rivets.js

Suppose I have the following object Data:

```
Data.events = []
Data.push = function() {
  this.events.push(arguments);
  this.emit('push')
}
```

I want to bind the Data.events array to a list:

```
<ol>
  <li data-each-event="events">
    <h1 data-text="event.name"></h1>
    <p data-text="event.data"></p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

How can I configure my adapter so that the DOM will update on('push')?

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.6.0, Rivets.js ships with a pretty flexible adapter that observes plain object properties as well as array mutations. Suppose you have the following template.

```
<ol>
  <li rv-each-event="data.events">
    <h1>{ event.name }</h1>
    <p>{ event.data }</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Just pass in the plain JavaScript objects directly when calling `rivets.bind`.

```
data.events = []
rivets.bind(el, {data: data})
```

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates this working out-of-the-box (note that this works in ES5 browsers only, but you can overwrite the built-in adapter with something that has the browser support you need).

http://jsfiddle.net/S6M7k/